# Regex: for each /xxx.png go to next /yyy.eps and change it to /xxx.eps

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to get a regex like so:

"for each `/xxx.png` go to the inmediately next `/yyy.eps`, and change it to `/xxx.eps`"

If possible, how could I do it with regex?
I'm working in a CSV file and using Notepad++.

Many thanks!

**EDIT**
Hoping this helps to clarify, a better example would be:

```
line 1: "landscape123.png","IwantToBeNamedlandscape123.eps"
line 2: "picture123.png","IdLikeToBeNamedpicture123.eps"
```

How can I take the pngs filenames and replace the next .eps filenames with them? Each time, both file types are on the same line.

Comment: an example with expected output would be better.

Comment: Show us an actual file, the pattern would involve more than just xxx and yyy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
^"(.*)\.png".*$
```

Replace with:

```
"\1.png","\1.eps"
```

This says: "Find lines that contain exactly: `"`, a filename (and capture the filename), `.png"`, and then whatever; and then replace them with `"\1.png","\1.eps"`", where `\1` is a backreference that contains the filename.

Make sure you have ". matches newline" unchecked.